# Alter a person's race from the command line.

Tags: command-line, graphics, icons, png

A disability project I'm building ([here](http://theopenvoicefactory.org) for your interest).  Uses a set of copyright-free icons.  Here are some examples of them in use.

[image]

It's bothering us that all of the icons are of white people.  We'd like to make them more diverse and representative.

The icons are pngs.  [Here's](http://designs.theopenvoicefactory.org/ed76ba77af4d515a2fc1e9505dea4bd0/icons/unknown112.png) an example.  I feel like there must be a command line way of replacing one colour with another.  If I had that, then I could do a lot of things semi-automatically, but I have NO idea if such a thing is possible.

Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace a specific color with another using ImageMagick or GraphicsMaqick.  In your screenshot, the "flesh" is color #FFEFC6.  Use `-fill newcolor -opaque oldcolor` to replace this color with another (and use "-fuzz 10%" to replace all pixels whose color is "close" to oldcolor):

```
magick pdzSe.png -fill black -fuzz 10% -opaque "#FFEFC6" black.png
magick pdzSe.png -fill orange -fuzz 10% -opaque "#FFEFC6" orange.png
magick pdzSe.png -fill brown -fuzz 10% -opaque "#FFEFC6"  brown.png
```

If you want to use GraphicsMagick, replace `magick` with `gm convert`, and if you want to use ImageMagick version 6, replace `magick` with `convert`.  If you're running on Windows, you'll need to replace the `%` with `%%`.

[image: Resulting images]

This should be enough to get you started, but it's a crude solution that doesn't account for blended pixels such as those appearing in your sample "thumbs-up" icon.  Below are the results of running the same commands against "thumbs-up", enlarged 4x so you can see the "halo" effect around the edges of the "flesh".  Getting rid of the "halos" will require more work, specific to your icon set.  Ideally you'd have the original vector art-work to update, but I suppose that's not the case.
[image: results]

In fact, the original artwork is available at [straight-street.com](http://straight-street.com) (search for "good") and working with the original SVG files is much simpler; there is no "halo" issue.  Here I just used a text editor to change the color FFEFC6 to FF8888:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! That's just the sort of response I was looking for :) I've upvoted now. I'll come back and accept when I've pressed the buttons at this end :)